# How to start mongodb console

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I started mongodb by the command

```
mongod --dbpath ./data/
```

My app is able to save and retrieve data from the mongodb with the above server but when I go to mongo console from other terinal tab using

```
$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
> show collections
>
```

it doesn't show any collections. Is the mongodb connecting to another database? How do I connect to my db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command:

```
use <database name>
```

where you replace `<database name>` with the name of your database that you want to connect to

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following command to show all databases:

```
show dbs
```